# Probability of winning pattern

Tags: probability, algorithms

$N$ players decide to play a coin-flipping game, which they first decide to pick a $k$-length pattern (e.g, for $N=2, k=3$, Alice picks $HHT$, BOB picks $THT$, etc.). The coin is kept flipping until one pattern is realized. What will be each person's winning chance?

I guess we can enumerate to calculate the probabilities when both $N$ and $k$ are small. But what we $N$ and $k$ are large, can we come up with a generalized solutions (without using Monte Carlo)?

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting?  For small sizes you can certainly work it out via Markov states.  Conway et. al. have [looked at this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoinTossing.html) and found some "paradoxical" facts.  For example, whatever triple you pick, your opponent can find a better one.  Not intuitive, but of course there's no transitivity to these things.

Comment: Recommend watching [Numberphile's video on Penney's Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa9jLWKrX0c) which discusses the fact that whatever the first player chooses, with that information the second player can pick a choice which is more likely to occur first.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of how to compute the competing probabilities via Markov chains and "absorbing states" would be helpful to the OP.